# How to convert ByteArrayInputStream into file or image

Tags: scala, playframework

I have this code

def test(base64: String) {
    Logger.debug("ImageHelper.test")

```
var test = Base64.getDecoder.decode(base64);   

// var input_stream: ByteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(test);
var input_stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(test);

// var final_buffered_image: BufferedImage = ImageIO.read(input_stream);

// ImageIO.write(final_buffered_image , "jpg", new File("final_file.jpg") );

    val size100     = Image.fromStream(new FileInputStream(base64)).scaleTo(100, 100)
// val size100   = Image.fromStream(input_stream).scaleTo(100, 100) }
```

How do I convert the input_stream variable(Which is a  ByteArrayInputStream) to a file or image?

Comment: You have an `InputStream` - just pass it to the method instead of your strange `FileInputStream` construction.

Comment: What do you mean sir?

Comment: `Image.fromStream(input_stream)`